# INSERT Select Statement

Tags: mysql, sql

What is wrong with my following statement?

```
INSERT INTO studentenrolledteacher (student_id,teacher,subject) VALUES   select student_id from studentprofile WHERE lastname='marco','1','2'
```

Comment: Delete `VALUES`.  Then learn how to use prepared statements in PHP.

Comment: When I delete the Values I got this error message  MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '(select student_id from studentprofile WHERE lastname='marco'),'G','FG')' at line 2

Answer (score 2):

You want `insert . . . select`.  `Values` is not part of the syntax:

```
insert into studentenrolledteacher (student_id, teacher, subject)
    select student_id, 1, 2
    from studentprofile 
    where lastname = 'marco';
```

Comment: When I delete the Values I got this error message MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '(select student_id from studentprofile WHERE lastname='marco'),'G','FG')' at line 2

Comment: @allanpaculan . . . The answer shows the correct syntax.

Comment: By the way, how can I change marco to PHP variable like $LastName. Everytime I insert data for marco using $LastName no data is inserted in the lastname column.

Comment: @allanpaculan . . . You need to learn to use parameters to pass such values from PHP into SQL queries.

Comment: sir can you help me this $result = $conn->query("INSERT INTO studentenrolledteacher (student_id,studentlastname,stime,sday,leclab,subjectcode,description,lec,lab,unit,teacher) VALUES 
   ((select student_id from studentprofile WHERE lastname='$lastname'),'$studentlastname','$stime','$sday','$leclab','$subjectcode','$description','$lec','$lab','$unit','$teacher')");  if I change $lastname to 'marco' it insert the student_id of marco if I use $lastname blank column. Thank you.